How can i implement a client in .net with dotnetty that makes requests over tcp and waits for response?
I am developing an application in .net that acts like a tcp client that needs to keep a connection open to one external system, which eventually sends events that hace to read. For this I use the dotnetty library and the use of an inboundhandler. Sometimes it is necessary to send a request to the external system for which I expect to receive a response, this model must be synchronous. Is there a way to implement this request/response model where I make a request and wait for the response?
I have a simpleinboundhandler to read events, but need a way to make request and wait for the response in a synchronous way. The solution has to be implemented using dotnetty library
